# User email is not coming in facebook login api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-login

I tried to add Facebook credential to my website. But except name and Facebook ID, other details are not returned.

```html
<?php
include_once("includes/access_login.php");
include_once("facebook/facebook.php");
    define('YOUR_APP_ID', '16604785137509701');


    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => '16607854137509701',
      'secret' => '5cfdea08254bb6637d064924a73e5c508',
    ));

    $userId = $facebook->getUser();

    echo "FB User Id : " . $userId;

    $userInfo = $facebook->api('/me');

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($userInfo);
    echo "</pre>";

?>
```

[image]

I have used these things. I am getting

```html
FB User Id : 902204443331431759

Array
(
    [name] => sradha
    [id] => 902204443331431759
)
```

but not the other details. Suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider the fact that not every logged in user has an email assigned to their account.

Take a look here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-email

Regards.

Comment: but i have tested with an account having a valid email id

Comment: Then, you should check your account configuration or request that permission for your app.

Comment: Hii,i have addeda screenshot.Here email permission is present

Comment: Can you try to run this code? it worked for me.

FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected'){
        FB.api('/me?fields=id,email,name', function(data) {
        console.log( data.email )
    })
}, {scope: 'email'});

Comment: How to use it and where?I am little bit confuse.

Comment: It is javascript, do you know how to use it?

Comment: Yes ,but i don't need it.I am using simple php code to do it.Thats why i am asking .Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Some users may have logged in with Phone Number and some may blocked their email for puclic access so in those cases there is no way to get their email unless they provide public access.

Comment: Ok but i have tested with an account having a valid email id